# How to show an .alert from the DataController

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, app-store-connect

I'm trying to set up an alert inside my `DataController' file, without any success!

In a SwiftUI View, I could do it easily, like that :

```
// Before the body
@State private var showAlert = false

// Inside the body
.onTapGesture { showAlert.toggle() }
.alert("There is an error", isPresented: $showAlert) { }
```

But in my `DataController`, I literally don't know how to perform it:

```
// DataController.swift
struct DataController {

    static let shared = DataController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {

        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ItemModel")

        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in

            if let error = error {
                // SOMETHING HERE?
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)!")
            }

            // print("Core Data succeed to load!")

        })

        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true

    }

    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        // try? context.save()

        do {
            try context.save()
            // print("Core Data succeed to save!")
        } catch {
            // SOMETHING HERE?
            print("Core Data failed to save!")
        }

    }

    // Some other functions below...

}
```

Do you have any idea? :D

[EDIT]

Here's my function create, for example:

```
func createItem( /* Some stuff here */ ) {

    let item = Item(context: context)

    /* Some stuff here */

    save(context: context)

}
```

And here's how I call it in a SwiftUI View:

```
// Inside a button
DataController.shared.createItem( /* Some stuff here */ )
presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

Comment: No you should not, definitely not. Remove the do/catch and let the method throw the error instead. Alerts are handled in the view and catching  the error is either done in the view or (better) in the view model / view controller depending on how this function is called.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you show me how to do it? I'll update the post to show you how I use this `DataController`.

Comment: First of all, that is not enough information to provide an answer and secondly , this is both a large and important topic so you should research it yourself so you get a good understanding about it. I am talking about error handling and when/how to throw errors and how to catch them and what to do with them like logging or showing alerts to the user.

Comment: Actually, I've been looking for an idea (or a solution) on Internet the entire weekend and I'm still stuck, what's why I'm asking for help...

Comment: Like the above comment suggests, add `throws` to the end of your `func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext)` signature, remove the `do/catch` from within that function. Then, when you call `save` inside your view, use `do/catch` there and in the event that `catch` is hit, set `showAlert` to `true`.

Comment: The correct solution for the question is suggested above, which is to catch the error *and* set the alert inside the view. A more complex alternative would be to have a view model (marked as `@MainActor`) handling all alerts of the app: the `isPresented` parameter would read from a view model variable. But that requires handling concurrent alerts, for example with a queue.

Comment: Actually, I don't even succeed to put a `throws` somewhere without any error so...