# How to load the PersistentStores in a correct way?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I've been looking on Internet the entire weekend and today on how to handle correctly any error when the PersistentStores loads, without a success!

Actually, so many people are looking for the same solution but no one gets an answer. For example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swift/core-data-error-checking/3794

Apple give us a `fatalError` in their template while telling us to not use it for a shipping application.

Here's also how you can have it, from many tutorials on Youtube, for example:

```
container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)!")
    }

    print("Core Data succeed to load!")

})
```

As I'm not able to handle a potential error, because I still don't know how to do it, I'd love to just load it without handling any error ; but I can't just delete the `if` and the `print` and leave it blank. So, what should I put inside?

Comment: Well, you probably should handle the error. You have suggestions in your [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71992007/how-to-show-an-alert-from-the-datacontroller) about how to do this. But, technically, you *could* just remove the `if let error = error` block and ignore it (again, not recommended).

Comment: No one is going to be able to "give [you] some code" because it's unclear what you want to do in the event that an error occurs. If you want to show an alert, again, refer to the comments in your past question. If you want to print to the console, you've already done that.

Comment: Core Data isn't easy to learn but this is about basic error handling and is not specific to Core Data so instead of looking for a quick fix I think you should learn about error handling as I wrote in your earlier question. As for the very specific scenario of setting up the persistent store I use fatalError, either it works fine or the app is unusable anyway so one might as well exit.

Comment: Actually for the save function I can almost do it even if I show a basic error message but in this situation I can't do the same thing. Also, Apple tell us to not use fatalError whereas it seems to be what should be done. Weird. You fatalError is equivalent to what Apple give us in the sample? Or have you improved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesn't have a straightforward answer because what you do depends on what your app does and how you want it to respond in this situation. Every app's requirements are different, and you have not given any indication of yours.

If this error happens, your app has failed to load the persistent store. Whatever data might have been in that store is not available. New data cannot be saved to that store. What should you do? What *can* you do, in your app, to meet your requirements? *What do you want your app to do if this persistent store is not available?* What would you consider to be a reasonable response, in your specific app? That is what you do here.

There's no real recovery path; you can't simply make the error go away. You could try deleting the old persistent store and creating a new one. That would lose any previously saved data. Is that OK? It depends on you and your app. If you want to do that, look into the `destroyPersistentStore(at:, type:, options:)` function to remove it cleanly. Then try loading the store again, and a new one will be created.